# Тест приложения на различных телефонах

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

Я сделал приложение, которые крашится и сразу запускается на маленьком кругу девайсов. Одним из таких является Lenovo A5000. К сожалению, такого телефона нет в AVD Android Studio. Если создавать свой profile нужного телефона, то, как мне кажется, полностью его воссоздать не получится и какие-то аспекты потеряются. Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверять приложения на определенных девайсах, которых нет в стандартом AVD.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно поискать что то подходящее среди эмуляторов GenyMotion, но боюсь что такой модели там может не быть, поэтому для проверки на Lenovo придется только искать реальное устройство